# octave vectorize function application

Tags: function, octave, vectorization, apply

For a given (m by n) matrix `poly` I would like generate its
lines with the following expression:

`poly(i, :) = [X(i) X(i)^2 X(i)^3 ...  X(i)^p]`

I am given a (m by 1) `X` vector and the value p. 
My current solution is:

```
poly(:,1) = X;
for i = 2:p
    poly(:,i) = X.^i;
end;
```

My question is: is their any way to further vectorize this?
I also generated a cell array of functions that could be applied
to the matrix row by row, but I still had to loop.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, it's possible using (for example) the built-in helper function ones().

Step-through solution:

```
poly = ones(size(X,1),p  );
poly = poly .* X;
powers = 1:p;
poly = poly .^ powers;
```

One-liner:

```
poly = (ones(size(X,1),p) .* X) .^[1:p];
```

Comment: Tried it out, for the looped version with X=[1:10^3]' and p = 10^3 the time elapsed was 2.757 seconds on my computer.
The vectorized version ran in 0.004 seconds, quite a speedup!

Comment: I tried your code and it doesn't seem to work. Note that poly is a matrix of (m by n). The number of columns n = p + 1 where all of column one is the same as X. X is a vector of m by 1. Although it doesn't seem to fit is has given me ideas on using repmap and reshaping the result into a matrix.

Comment: Oh yes, the code works, and gives identical results to your algorithm. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: And since you loop from 2:p, n would be equal to p in your example... (i.e. not n = p+1 as you write above.)

Comment: Funny. I tried both your versions and I got an error. Must have messed up in the input on my side. I was getting a vector, not matrix. And yes you are correct n = p. Anyway I have redone this and it works. Apologies and thank you.

Comment: Ok, figured out my mistake. I was not transposing the X. :-(

Comment: No problem, glad that you found the problem ;)